# How to reduce the uses of CSS IDs and Classes in mark-up using HTML5 and CSS3?

Tags: html, css

How to reduce the uses of CSS IDs and Classes in mark-up using HTML5 and CSS3?

Which HTML5 tags and CSS3 properties can reduce the need of classes and IDs

Currently I know

```
       <header>
        <nav>
        <section>
        <article>
        <aside>
        <footer>
    <time>
    <figure>
    <dialog>
    <mark>
<figcaption>
<hgroup>
```

Answer (score 5):

The way these reference neighbors could be considered using less ids, and the html 5 tags with colons.  This came from the Mix 11 videos.

CSS pop up menu:

```
.menu > li > ul {display: none;}
.menu > li:hover > ul { display:block;}
```

Dependent content:

```
.faq > div {display:none;}
.faq > div:target {display:block;}
```

Validation:

```
:valid, :invalid, :required, :optional, :in-range, :out-of-range, 
:read-only, :read-write

#signup input:focus:required:valid + .val .invalid {display:none;}
#signup input:focus:required:invalid + .val .valid {display:none;}
```

Animations:

```
.faq > div {display:none;}
.faq > div:target {display:block;position:relative;
       -webkit-animation:throb 1.5s infinite;}
```

Comment: IDs are more efficient than those methods: http://css-tricks.com/efficiently-rendering-css/

Answer (score 4):

Pseudo classes can do that, such as `:first-child` and `:last-child`, the latter which is new in CSS3.

You are better off having a [look here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors).